# need correction with a snippet in functions.php

Tags: filters, plugin-gravity-forms

I use gravity forms and wp-favorites plugin (helps users select their favorite posts).

I am trying to auto-populate gravity form with the following snippet. It works pretty well but it shows only the first item in the list.

How can I get all items in the array?

```
add_filter("gform_field_value_circle", "populate_square");
function populate_square ($value) {
    $favs = wpfp_get_users_favorites();
    foreach ($favs as $fav){
        $list = get_the_title($fav);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

This snippet shows me the title of the first selected post only. I would like to get a list of all the selected posts, how do I acheive that ?

FYI, I am trying to make use of the HOOK provided by gravity forms. You can see the code [here](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Using_Dynamic_Population).

Pleae let me know if I need to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a dropdown and you want to populate it with options may be use this filter

```
add_filter("gform_predefined_choices", "add_predefined_choice");
function add_predefined_choice($choices){
   $choices["My New Choice"] = array("Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3");
   return $choices;
}
```

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_predefined_choices

gform_field_value_selection filter is for default value.

Give a look here http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs

<del>See if this works..</del>

```
  add_filter("gform_field_value_selection", "populate_selection");
    function populate_selection ($value) {
        $favs = wpfp_get_users_favorites();
        $list = array();
        foreach ($favs as $fav){
        $list[] = get_the_title($fav);
        }
        return $list;
    }
```

Comment: It returns a text 'Array'. Any thoughts ? Thank you.

Comment: @gurung have edited my answer..

Comment: No I did not edit your answer. and No it is not a drop down. But as indicated I have done a minor corrections in the parameter name and the function name, just to make sure they are not default values. I have also given a link to gravity forms to see the hook in action. Thank you for trying.

Comment: oops.. i thought you meant i edited your answer. Cn you help me further please. thnks

Comment: @gurung What kind of field it is? for ex. List field or some thing else?

Comment: Yes it is a list field. The function is supposed to grab the titles of the selected posts and show it in form of lists.